# All commands failing in powershell (4.0.) Even "c:" and "cd" and "dir"

Tags: powershell

I'm not sure when this started... whenever I open PowerShell, I can't execute even the most basic commands. I always get the following error message:

```
PS C:\> dir
dir : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name '.' does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ dir
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (.:String) [], DriveNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveNotFound
---
```

This had been working fine but now all of a sudden I can't do anything. I've tried removing PowerShell 4 and re-installing... no change. Sorry for the formatting here... It looks organized in my view above but the preview text looks horrid.

Comment: can you run some 'actual' powershell cmdlets. The ones above are aliases so just need to discount that it's just the aliases that are broken. e.g. `get-childitem`

Comment: Close PowerShell. Open your My Documents folder and locate the Windows PowerShell folder within it. Inside that should be your profile file. Rename it to make sure there are not commands in it conflicting or corrupting your session. Open PowerShell and see if it works now.

Comment: And does `Get-PSDrive` show `C` configured to use the `FileSystem` provider and rooted to C:\?

Comment: Do you get the same results when you log on to the workstation as a different user?

Comment: I have no files in My Documents that are called or seem related to powershell. I tried the "get-childitem" and "get-psdrive" commands mentioned above and they both generate the same error message (pasted below.) I tried them in Get-ChildItem mixed case and all-lower case. No cigar...

Comment: PS C:\> get-childitem
get-childitem : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name '.' does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ get-childitem
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (.:String) [], DriveNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveNotFound

PS C:\> get-psdrive
get-psdrive : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name '.' does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ get-psdrive
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (.:String) [], DriveNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveNotFound

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't remember ever having java installed, but looking at my regular %path% I see that %java_home% is in there, but the value is never used or defined anywhere. Once I removed that from my path, the error above went away.

Strange that it would even be an issue for powershell. You'd think it would just skip past a non-existent directory in my path and move onto the next one when resolving a command.